# Как с помощью регулярного выражения проверить есть ли перед символом определённый символ

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть номер телефона `+7 123 456-78-90`.

Нужно модифицировать регулярное выражение `/([0-9])/` для javascript таким образом, чтобы семерка после плюса не попала в результат обработки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще (но не в JavaScript, об этом ниже!), проверить, есть ли какая-то последовательность символов перед выражением
вы можете с помощью *zero length look-behind positive/negative assertion*:

Для positive:

```
(?<=foo)
```

И для negative:

```
(?<!foo)
```

В вашем случае это negative (не попала) и + вместо foo, если я правильно понимаю:

```
(?<![+])
```

Смысл данной конструкции в том, что вы проверяете, *есть ли что-то/нет ли чего-то* перед выражением, но это что-то не попадает внутрь самого выражения, а только является доволнительным условием (отсюда *zero length*).

Квадратные скобки вокруг `+` стоят, потому что `+` сам по себе является специальным символом и обрабатывается особенно. Чтобы забрать у него его магичность, нужно его экранировать или превратить в символьный класс, что я и сделал.

Подробнее о zero length assertions вы можете прочитать здесь:

- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) (англ.)

**Как же обстоят дела в JavaScript?**

Проблема в том, что JavaScript на данный момент не поддерживает пока что look-behind assertions, поэтому приходится его имитировать разными способами.

*Способ 1.* Простейший и наиболее популярный:

```
newString = string.replace(/([abcdefg])?m/, function($0,$1){ return $1?$0:'m';});
```

Здесь не выполняется никакой замены, это просто демонстрация, как сделать look behind assertion в JavaScript.

*Способ 2.* Другой — использовать look ahead assertion, но перед этим перевернуть строку и выражение! Здесь помогает то, что look ahead assertion JavaScript'ом поддерживается.

К перевёрнутой строке применяем:

```
[0-9](?![+])
```

Обратите внимание на то, что `[0-9]` здесь стоит сначала, перед `[+]`, и применяем мы это выражение тоже к перевернутой строке.

Подробнее:

- [Javascript: negative lookbehind equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641407/javascript-negative-lookbehind-equivalent) (англ.)

Comment: А теперь я вам испорчу настроение: JS не умеет look-behind. :)

Comment: @Athari: Да, это правда, большое спасибо за очень правильное замечание

Answer (score 0):

Можно модифицировать саму обработку, чтобы она брала из совпадения группу, а не всё совпадение.

```
"+7 123 456-78-90".match(/([0-9])/g)
// ["7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

"+7 123 456-78-90".match(/\+\d|([0-9])/g)
// ["+7", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

var res = [];
"+7 123 456-78-90".replace(/\+\d|([0-9])/g, function (match, digit) { digit && res.push(digit) });
res
// ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
```

Обрати внимание, что replace используется как forEach с группами, результат замены не используется.